# Is there a way to use the firebase push() method without their auto generated IDs?

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

So I have a path called game_bans, and I want it to store the game bans by the user id, not the auto generated ID.

I'd like for it to save like this;

[image: screenshot]

But the way it works is;

[image: screenshot]

Comment: The documentation starts with a list of ways you can write data.  I suggest reading it.  push is not your only option. https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/save-data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ref` and `set`.
I don't know your code, but something like:

```
database.ref('/game_bans/' + bannedUserId).set({moderator: ... });
```